# limit execution of a function for specified user at one per minute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a route like this to execute a function:

```
router.post('/send-verification-again', sendVerificationAgain);
```

At the function above we have the email or phone number of the account in which we want to verify.

This will execute a function to send an email or sms to the user with his/her verification code ok?

Apparently we don't want the user to be able to send more than one request per minute to this route, right?

How can I limit execution of a function for specified user at one per minute?

```
function sendVerificationAgain(email) {
  // for each specific email here the function can be executed one time per minute
}
```

This is very common functionality, is there any convention to do this?

Comment: Good answer by Kelvin below. You can also check out libraries such as: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply store the email for a minute and check if it's stored:

```js
const recentlySent = new Set();

function sendVerificationAgain(email) {
    if (recentlySent.has(email)) return;
    recentlySent.add(email);
    setTimeout(() => recentlySent.delete(email), 60e3);
    // ...
}
```

You might also want to first normalize the email, e.g. lowercase it.

For more information, look up "debounce" in the programming sense